# How to limit the results of a SQL query by group

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
select article_number, date, company, size, price 
from price 
order by article_number, company, date
```

that produces these results:

```
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:06:12.872955', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:13:55.311955', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:06:12.872955', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:13:55.311955', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20') ...
```

I want to limit the results for each `article_number` and `company` selection so that it only show 2 results with 2 last different dates. So the result should look like:

```
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', '2B', '20', '645,75')

('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20') ...
```

Can anyone help me how to do this? A simple limit 2 at the end will only give out 2 results at all and not for each "group"

THX!

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: I added this details: sqlite3 in python

Comment: SQLIte: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751399/sql-query-how-to-apply-limit-within-group-by

Comment: I created a new question and I would be very happy if you would like to have a look at it. I think it is easy for you and I would be very happy about a solution! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870097/how-to-sort-a-table-by-the-difference-in-percent-between-prices-on-different-dat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so for ORACLE, POSTGRESQL, SQL-SERVER can use ROW_NUMBER() like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select article_number, date, company, size, price ,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY article_number,company ORDER BY date DESC) as rnk
    from price )
WHERE rnk <= 2
order by article_number, company, date
```

Solution for MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select t.article_number, t.date, t.company, t.size, t.price , count(*) as rnk
    from price t
    INNER JOIN price s
    ON(t.article_number = s.article_number and t.company = s.company and t.date <= s.date)
    GROUP BY t.article_number,t.company,t.date,t.size,t.price
)
WHERE rnk <= 2
order by article_number, company, date
```

**EDIT** : I see its sqlite, try the second solution for MYSQL, it should work for sqlite as well..

Comment: The first one returns error "near (" and the second one just don't give me a result back. But in general it should work like that

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine Typo, forgot the group by.. try it now

Comment: Do you maybe also know how to give out only Article Numbers for a company that changed price?

Comment: Maybe, but it hard to understand what you want like this.. Open a new question and explain it:) @Eternal_Sunshine

Comment: I mean just sort all groups by the biggest difference between price of 1 and 2

Comment: I'm sry, its hard to understand.. you seen how much time it took us just to understand each other about the relation..

Comment: I created a new question and I would be very happy if you would like to have a look at it. I think it is easy for you and I would be very happy about a solution! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870097/how-to-sort-a-table-by-the-difference-in-percent-between-prices-on-different-dat

Answer (score 0):

If Oracle:

Add
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLNAME ORDER BY COLNAME ) RN

as column and wrap your query in a SELECT query. In the parent query then use the RN column to limit the results per group.

Comment: I created a new question and I would be very happy if you would like to have a look at it. I think it is easy for you and I would be very happy about a solution! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870097/how-to-sort-a-table-by-the-difference-in-percent-between-prices-on-different-dat

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic solution which you can use in almost all RDMBS which don't support `partition by`

```
select article_number,date, company, size, price from 
(
    select p1.article_number,p1.company,
    count(p1.date) as rno,
    max(p1.date) as date,max(p1.size) as size,max(p1.price) as price
    from price p1 
     inner join price p2
    on p1.article_number=p2.article_number 
     and p1.company=p2.company 
     and p1.date<=p2.date
    group by p1.article_number,p1.company,p1.date
) t1
where t1.rno<=2
```

Comment: I created a new question and I would be very happy if you would like to have a look at it. I think it is easy for you and I would be very happy about a solution! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870097/how-to-sort-a-table-by-the-difference-in-percent-between-prices-on-different-dat