# How to sort a table by the difference in percent between prices on different date

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
select t.article_number, t.date, t.company, t.size, t.price , count(*) as rnk
from price t
INNER JOIN price s
ON(t.article_number = s.article_number and t.company = s.company and t.date <= s.date)
    GROUP BY t.article_number,t.company,t.date,t.size,t.price
)

    WHERE rnk <= 2
    order by article_number, company, date
```

that works on this data:

```
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:06:12.872955', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:13:55.311955', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', '2B', '20', '635,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', '2B', '20', '645,75')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:06:12.872955', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:13:55.311955', 'Bio', '20', '423,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', 'Bio', '20', '403,20')
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20') ...
```

It produces output like this:

```
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', '2B', '20', '635,75', 2)
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', '2B', '20', '645,75', 1)

('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', 'Bio', '20', '403,20', 2)
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20', 1) ...
```

But I want to sort this output by the biggest difference in price between these two dates. So it should look like this:

```
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', 'Bio', '20', '403,20', 2)
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', 'Bio', '20', '423,20', 1)

('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:47:13.737155', '2B', '20', '645,75', 2)
('50240-20', '2016-03-08 13:51:32.677155', '2B', '20', '635,75', 1) ...
```

Because the price of the top product changed 4,7% and the second changed 1,6%

I hope you understand what I mean and maybe can suggest a solution because I'm not that good in sql. I'm using sqlite3 with python.

Thank you very much!

Comment: by change you mean increased or it could be increased or decreased both

Comment: Yes biggest difference in percentage. No matter if positive or negative

Answer (score 0):

- Assuming that sqlite3 uses `cte`, you can use something like this.
- I used `date1` as `date` and `size1` as `size` as my DB doesn't let me use these keywords.
- The `price` format should be changed to `decimal` rather than `string`.

This is query I tried in Oracle using Common Type Expression. If sqlite doesn't support it, you have to replace the query of each derived table with main query. (like whereever I used `tbl1`, you have to use the query which is used to derive `tbl1` and so on.

```
with tbl1 as
(select p1.article_number,p1.company,count(p1.date1) as rno,max(p1.date1) as date1,max(p1.size1) as size1,max(p1.price) as price
from price p1 inner join price p2
on p1.article_number=p2.article_number and p1.company=p2.company and p1.date1>=p2.date1
group by p1.article_number,p1.company,p1.date1
)
,tbl2 as
(select p1.article_number,p1.company,count(p1.date1)+1 as rno,max(p1.date1) as date1,max(p1.size1) as size1,max(p1.price) as price
from price p1 inner join price p2
on p1.article_number=p2.article_number and p1.company=p2.company and p1.date1>=p2.date1
group by p1.article_number,p1.company,p1.date1
)
,tbl3 as
(
select tbl1.*,
case when tbl1.price>tbl2.price then ((tbl1.price-tbl2.price)/tbl1.price)*100
else ((tbl2.price-tbl1.price)/tbl1.price)*100 end as diff_percent
from tbl1 inner join tbl2 
on tbl1.article_number=tbl2.article_number and tbl1.company=tbl2.company
and tbl1.rno=tbl2.rno
order by tbl1.article_number,tbl1.company,tbl1.rno
)
,tbl4 as(
select t1.article_number,t1.company,count(t1.diff_percent) as rnk,max(t1.date1) as date1,max(t1.price) as price,max(t1.diff_percent) as diff_percent
from tbl3 t1 inner join tbl3 t2
on t1.article_number=t2.article_number and t1.company=t2.company
and t1.diff_percent <=t2.diff_percent
group by t1.article_number,t1.company,t1.diff_percent
)
select * from tbl4 
where rnk <=2
order by article_number,company,date1
```