# SQLite query with LIMIT per column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to compose a query with a where condition to get multiple unique sorted columns without having to do it in multiple queries. That is confusing so here is an example...

Price Table

```
id | item_id | date | price
```

I want to query to find the most recent price of multiple items given a date. I was previously iterating through items in my application code and getting the most recent price like this...

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE item_id = ? AND date(date) < date(?) ORDER BY date(date) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Iterating through each item and doing a query is too slow so I am wondering if there is a way I can accomplish this same query for multiple items in one go. I have tried `UNION` but I cannot get it to work with the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` commands like this thread says (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1415380/4400804) for MySQL

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (based on adapting the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432610/how-to-select-last-5-results-from-each-user-id-in-an-sqlite-database)):

```
SELECT * FROM prices a WHERE a.RowId IN (
  SELECT b.RowId
    FROM prices b
    WHERE a.item_id = b.item_id AND date < ?
    ORDER BY b.item_id LIMIT 1
) ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions (Available with sqlite 3.25 and newer) will likely help:

```
WITH ranked AS
 (SELECT id, item_id, date, price
       , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY item_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
  FROM prices
  WHERE date < ?)
SELECT id, item_id, date, price
FROM ranked
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY item_id;
```

will return the most recent of each `item_id` from all records older than a given date.

Answer (score 0):

```
I would simply use a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

SELECT p.*
FROM prices p
WHERE p.DATE = (SELECT MAX(p2.date)
                FROM prices p2
                WHERE p2.item_id = p.item_id
               );
```

This is phrase so it works on all items.  You can, of course, add filtering conditions (in the outer query) for a given set of items.

Answer (score 0):

With `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT p.* FROM prices p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM prices
  WHERE item_id = p.item_id AND date > p.date
)
```

or with a join of the table to a query that returns the last `date` for each `item_id`:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM prices p INNER JOIN (
  SELECT item_id, MAX(date) date
  FROM prices 
  GROUP BY item_id
) t ON t.item_id = p.item_id AND t.date = p.date
```