# Django ORM Get first row for each group

Tags: python, sql, django

I want to be able to get the first row of each group of id & type, I'll give and example :

```
Type  Id   terms   data_signed   is_agreed
----------------------------------------
BUY   1     31      20-01-01         Y
BUY   1     12      19-01-01         Y
BUY   3     99      20-01-01         N
SELL  2     42      19-01-01         N
SELL  2     15      20-01-01         Y
SELL  2     87      20-01-01         Y
```

I want the result to be

```
Type  Id   terms   data_signed   is_agreed
----------------------------------------
BUY   1     31      20-01-01         Y
BUY   3     99      20-01-01         N
SELL  2     42      19-01-01         N
```

the records are already ordered by type->id
I just want to fetch the first row of each type&field values

couldn't use distinct() since I'm not using PosgreSQL,

do you have any ideas?

Comment: no distingt is wrong, but what is litesql?

Comment: edited my message, i meant im not using postresql

Comment: Ok, what are ou using when you are not using postgres?

Comment: sqlite, it seem like an easy task but I cant seem to solve this with django :(

Comment: i am a ltlle unsure what you are trying to achieve, that is a task for sqlite, django is imfo a framework for web, so it wouldn't do sql by it self, you could use dataframes, but stull sqllite is the way to go

Comment: I just want to use Django methods to achieve what is described in the post.
when using 
all_objects = all_objects.order_by('type', 'id').distinct('type', 'id')
I'm getting an error

Comment: `Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>`

Comment: see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/ there you can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751399/sql-query-how-to-apply-limit-within-group-by

Comment: it should work on both SQLite (my unit test environment) and PostgreSQL, that's why I'm trying to do it with the abstraction of Django ORM

Comment: the code with row_number, will worl with sqllite and postgres, when the tables are identical

Comment: Show your model. And your example could be SELL with Id= 1 for example?

Comment: I just want the first row of each group of {BUY, SELL...}

Comment: What you want is theoretically impossible (although practically there could be some tricks). The reason it is impossible is that the request is ambiguous. You said you want the **first** row of each group but you don't give any ordering rule to determine the first row. This ordering rule must be deterministic (meaning the sorting key must be unique, otherwise your DB won't be able to figure out which one is the first one). It would be interesting to know the idea behind this query, because it looks a lot like an XY problem. What do you want to do with the query result *in fine*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the desired order within each group? It's not consistent in your example. Without this it's impossible to determine which in the table is "the first":

However, if you can decide on a third field to order by, then you could use [window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions) which sqlite and postgresql both support. This example supposes that your model is `Entry` and the field by which to order each group is `terms`

```py
from django.db.models import F, Min, Window

Entry.objects.annotate(
    lowest_terms=Window(
        expression=Min('terms'),
        partition_by=[F('type'), F('id')],
        order_by=F('terms')
    )
).filter(lowest_terms=F('terms'))
```

Cheeky and not really what window functions are designed for but that should work

Note: if your live environment uses postgres, you should really try to set up your dev environment with a postgres server too and use `distinct()`